# multiprocessing of function with constant and iterable arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

Hi stackoverflow users,

I tried to look this up but couldn't find an answer: I essentially like to process a function in parallel (independent processes!) and the function has one iterable (`x`) *and* several constant arguments (`k`, `d`). Here is a very simplified example:

```
from multiprocessing import *

def test_function(args):
    k = args[0]
    d = args[1]
    x = args[2]
    del args

    return k*x + d

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=2)

    k = 3.
    d = 5.

    constants = [k,d]
    xvalues = range(0,10)
    result = [pool.apply_async(test_function, constants.append(i)) for i in xvalues]

    output = [r.get() for r in result]

    print output
    #I expect [5.0, 8.0, 11.0, 14.0, 17.0, 20.0, 23.0, 26.0, 29.0, 32.0]
```

This gives me the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_function.py", line 23, in <module>
    output = [r.get() for r in result]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python2.7\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 528, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: test_function() argument after * must be a sequence, not NoneType
```

So my questions are:

What does this error message actually mean?

How do I fix it to get the expected results (see last line of code example)?

Is there a better/working/elegant way for the line that calls apply_sync?

FYI: I'm new here and to python, please bear with me and let me know if my post needs more details.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does this error message actually mean?

The value returned by the `append` method is always `None`, hence when doing:

```
pool.apply_async(test_function, constants.append(i))
```

you are calling `pool.apply_asynch` with `None` as `args` argument, but `apply_asynch` expects an *iterable* as argument. What `apply_asynch` is doing is called [`tuple`-unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments).

> How do I fix it to get the expected results?

To achieve the expected output simple concatenate the `i` to the constants:

```
pool.apply_asynch(test_function, (constants + [i],))
```

> Is there a better/working/elegant way for the line that calls
>   apply_sync?

Note that you have to wrap all the arguments into a one element tuple, since your `test_function` accepts a single argument.
You could modify it in this way:

```
def test_function(k, d, x):
    # etc
```

And simply use:

```
pool.apply_asynch(test_function, constants + [i])
```

The [`apply_asynch`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async) will automatically unpack the `args` into the three arguments of the function using `tuple`-unpacking. (read carefully the documentation for `Pool.apply` and friends).

---

> Is there a better/working/elegant way for the line that calls
>   apply_sync?

As pointed out by Silas instead of using `Pool.apply_asynch` to a list of values you should use the [`Pool.map`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) or `Pool.map_asynch` methods, which do that for you.

For example:

```
results = pool.map(test_function, [(constants + [i],) for i in xvalues])
```

However note that in this case `test_function` must accept a single argument, so you have to manually unpack the constants and the `x`, like you were doing in your question.

---

Also, as general suggestion:

- In your `test_function` there is absolutely no need to do `del args`. It will only *slow down* the execution of the function(by a very little amount). Use `del` sparingly, only when needed.
- Instead of assigning by hand the elements from the tuple you can use the syntax:

  ```
  k, d, x = args
  ```

  Which is equivalent to the (possibly slightly slower):

  ```
  k = args[0]
  d = args[1]
  x = args[2]
  ```
- Expect big *slow downs* using `multiprocessing` to call such simple functions. The cost to communicate and synchronize processes is pretty big, hence you must avoid calling simple function, and whenever possible try to work "in chunks"(e.g. instead of sending each request separately, send a list of 100 requests to a worker in a single argument).

Comment: He'd probably be better served by `pool.map` or `pool.map_asynch` in any case.

Comment: Thanks for your great reply and to Silas for the addition! I included all suggestions, but had to modify the pool.map line to the following: `result = pool.map(test_function, [constants + [i] for i in xvalues])` And also the subsequent line with `.get()` is actually unnecesssary, printing `result` gives the correct answer. Thanks also for the general suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

constants.append(i) returns None , you should append the values first, and then use `constants` as the second parameter.

```
>>> constants = []
>>> i = 2
>>> bug_value = constants.append(i)
>>> constants
[2]
>>> bug_value is None
True
>>>
```

Use `result = [pool.apply_async(test_function, constants+ [i]) for i in xvalues]` indeed

list + list appends the two lists and returns the resulting list.

Comment: Thanks for your concise example! My problem was that I expected something like a concatenation from `constants.append.(i)`.